# Asana addProject trouble in node

Tags: node.js, asana

I'm trying to create a task and then set a project on the task using nodejs and the asana thin wrapper available from npm.

```
var asana = require('asana');
var newTask = { name: "Your Mission", notes: "Stuff" };
var project = [{ id:321, name: "Missions Impossible"}];

var client = asana.Client.basicAuth('APIKEY');

client.tasks.createInWorkspace(123, newTask).then(function(task) {

    client.tasks.addProject(task.id, project).then(function(o) {

        // Check for empty object returned (sign of success)

        if (Object.keys(o).length === 0)
            console.log('yay!');
        else
            console.log('booo');
}
```

The task is created, but I get an error in the addProject method - "Possibly unhandled error. Invalid Request".
I've tried different variations on the project object, but I'm out of ideas.

Is the project wrongly formed? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, your `project` is malformed. The `data` passed to the `addProject` method should be a dictionary with the member:

`project: 321`

or

`project: { id: 321 }`

See the [documentation](http://developer.asana.com/documentation-preview/#tasks) for the endpoint being called and the data that it gets passed.

Comment: Your answer is a bit unclear, as JavaScript has no 'dictionary' object, but setting my project = { project: 321 } worked. Setting the project = 321 does NOT work. The Asana documentation is nice, but it's rather ambiguous.

Thanks for the answer, tho, finally working!